# SubConsulta en Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, orm, sql

Hola a todos quiero realizar el siguiente query en Rails pero solo me esta dando los valores nulos de una tabla sin observar la otra.

```
SELECT P.id FROM pets P WHERE P.id NOT IN (SELECT pet_id FROM sponsors);
```

Lo esta tratando de realizar de la siguiente forma pero no funciona.

```
Pet.where.not(id: Sponsor)
```

que deuelve

```
SELECT  "pets".* FROM "pets" WHERE "pets"."id" IS NOT NULL LIMIT $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución de la siguiente manera:

```
Pet.where.not(id: Sponsor.select("pet_id")).select("id")
```

Que retorna:

```
SELECT  "pets"."id" FROM "pets" WHERE "pets"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "sponsors"."pet_id" FROM "sponsors")
```